# Cardinality of some sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We have a set $S\subseteq P(X)$ such that $X\in S$ and $|S|=c$, where $c=|\mathbb{R}|$ (for some set $X$).
Then, we define $S^*$ the family of all $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ where, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $A_n\in S$ or $X\setminus A_n\in S$.

I want to prove that $|S^*|= c$. Clearly, $S\subseteq S^*$, so $c\le |S^*|$. So I want to prove that $|S^*|\le c$.

This is what I have tried:

Define $f:S^*\to S^{\aleph_0}$ by $f\left(\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\right)=(A_1',A_2',...)$, where $A_j'=A_j$ if $A_j\in S$, and $A_j'=X\setminus A_j$ if $X\setminus A_j\in S$.

My problem is that I can't prove $f$ is a function, and even if it is, I don't know if it will be injective.

Any hint? Thanks.

Comment: For each $T\in S^*$ choose a representation. The same $T$ may have several, so fix one. Once that's done, have $f$ have range not $S^{\aleph_0}$ but instead $(S\times 2)^{\aleph_0}$, and map each $T$ not just to the sequence of $A_i'$, but rather to the sequence of pairs $(A_i',j_i)$, where $j_i=0$ is $A_i'=A_i$, and $1$ otherwise. This map is clearly well-defined and injective.

Answer (score 1):

As Andres Caicedo put it in the comments:

> For each $T \in S^*$ choose a representation. The same $T$ may have several, so fix one. Once that's done, have $f$ have range not $S^{\aleph_0}$ but instead $(S\times2)^{\aleph_0}$, and map each $T$ not just to the sequence of $A'_i$, but rather to the sequence of pairs $(A'_i,j_i)$, where $j_i=0$ if $A'_i = A_i$, and $1$ otherwise. This map is clearly well-defined and injective.